# Batch File - Using List, move files from folders

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have 3 folders located in a INPUT folder.
Also have 3 folders in a OUTPUT folder like so...

```
"INPUT"
 -Folder1
 -Folder2
 -Folder3

"OUTPUT"
 -Folder1
 -Folder2
 -Folder3
```

I have a file listing (list.txt) from INPUT\Folder1.
I need it to read each line from the list.txt, and if exists as a file, then move those to the OUTPUT destination folders respectfully.

Here's what I have right now, but it copies all files over to the destination folders and not just what is in the list.txt:

```
for /f %%f in (%CD%\list.txt) do robocopy %CD%\INPUT\folder1 
%CD%\OUTPUT\folder1
for /f %%f in (%CD%\list.txt) do robocopy %CD%\INPUT\folder2 
%CD%\OUTPUT\folder2
for /f %%f in (%CD%\list.txt) do robocopy %CD%\INPUT\folder3 
%CD%\OUTPUT\folder3
```

Comment: read `robocopy /?` (again). It's `robocopy <sourceDIR> <destinationDIR> [<filemask>]`. So basically you copy the whole directory `<number of lines in list.txt>` times.

Comment: I don't know for sure if you realize I am trying to copy files from a list.txt to a seperate folder, but only the strings listed and not the whole dir. I read robocopy and even though I am unfamiliar with it for the most part, I am learning and trying to.  But I am a little confused as to see how this will copy only over the files that are listed in the text and not all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
Decided to try xcopy and throw in the "delims=*" for spaces and special characters in the filenames and it worked!

```
For /f "delims=*" %%f in (list.txt) do xcopy "%CD%\INPUT\folder1\%%f" 
%CD%\OUTPUT\folder1
```

So now it will only copy over the files listed in the list.txt.